# I can't upload an image using Vue 2.6 & Laravel 8.5 (Docker app)

Tags: file-upload, vuejs2, laravel-8

I need upload image in to public folder. Normal thing, I have already solved a similar problem and I didn't have a problem with it. But now, i don't understand, where can be a problem.

My Vue data:
[Vue data image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZwN7.jpg)

My Axios function:

```
this.productImages.forEach( image => {

    let data = new FormData()
    data.set('image', image.file)

    console.log(image.file)

    axios.post('/api/image', data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }})
        .then( response => {
            console.log( response.data.status )
            this.uploading.status = "Images uploading."
        })
        .catch( errors => {
            console.log("uploading error")
        })
    });
}
```

Console log for image.file look like this:
[Console log for image.file image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulqle.png)
I think, in this console log file look good, or ?

When i try check request from Laravel:
[Laravel store funcion without image save preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDnBV.png)

i get empty Object:
[Request console log image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH9uo.png)

When i try save image to public folder, like this:

```
$image->move( public_path('images/uploads'), "testName" );
```

I get an error message:

```
POST http://localhost/api/image 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Please, have somebody some ideas, where can be a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try without setting any headers, In my experience when `axios` receives a `FormData` object it automatically applies the correct headers and Laravel happily accepted the upload.
2. Try `append` instead of `set` as for some odd reason a while back, i recall `.set()` not working but `.append()` did instead even though I was setting one key value pair on `FormData`.

As for storing, make sure you have ran `php artisan storage:link`
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

You can configure a custom disk space in `config/filesystems.php` where you will find `'disks' => [ ... ]`

You could add a config as such to that array:

```php
        'uploads' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('public/uploads'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage/uploads',
            'visibility' => 'public'
        ],
```

Then to use that custom disk called `uploads`:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#automatic-streaming

```php
$file = $request->file('image');

Storage::disk('uploads')->putFileAs(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file, $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I try both axios settings .append() and .set() and a I am trying send image with and without header. But unsuccessfully. But it looks like the mistake will be in the axios calling, because if I try only save some file on disk "Storage::disk('uploads')->put('example.txt', 'Contents')" it works. But $file in Laravel request can't be validated. I can use $file->getClientOriginalExtension(), I can use $file->getClientOriginalName() but save still dont work.

Comment: When I try validate incoming file "$request->validate([  'image' => 'required' ]);" I get an error "POST http://localhost/api/image 422 (Unprocessable Entity)"

Comment: Ok, solved, i dont have set max_post_size for files in php.ini -_-

Comment: There are two max post size settings to watch out for in NGINX or one in Apache if you run into trouble in production with similar issue.